# Manipulating RGB values in PNG from command line

Tags: shell-script, image-manipulation

I'm looking for a command line tool/script which allows you to balance the colors in a PNG - similar to the "Adjust Color Balance" effect in Gimp (Colors > Color Balance...).

Something like this would be perfect:

```
rgbalance -r 20 -g 50 -b 40 *.png
```

Comment: there is `pnmgamma` it is part of pnm-tools. I don't know if it manipulated the image data, or the gamma values in the meta-data.

Comment: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#gamma

Comment: @richard  Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for.  Here is an usage example:  `pngtopnm input.png | pnmgamma 1.0 1.0 4.0 | pnmtopng > output.png`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is `pnmgamma` it is part of pnm-tools. I don't know if it manipulated the image data, or the gamma values in the meta-data.

Also Imagemagick, it can manipulate the image-data, or the gamma-metadata.

http://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#gamma